# Posting JSON via AJAX results in garbled request payload

Tags: ajax, datatables

Using JS Datatables jQuery plugin, I'm attempting to post JSON data to the server and use the JSON in the response to ultimately populate the datatable. However I've experiencing some strange behavior.

Using this code:

```
table_config.ajax = {
                "type": "POST",
                "url": $(location).attr('pathname'),
                "data": JSON.stringify({'member_id':2444}),
                "dataType": "json",
                "contentType": "application/json",
                "dataSrc": "results.data"
            };
```

I get a 400 HTTP response and the request payload looks like:

0=%7B&1=%22&2=m&3=e&4=m&5=b&6=e&7=r&8=_&9=i&10=d&11=%22&12=%3A&13=2&14=4&15=4&16=4&17=%7D

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are `stringify`ing something that is already a string in the `data` option.

Try:

```
table_config.ajax = {
            "type": "POST",
            "url": $(location).attr('pathname'),
            "data": { member_id: 2444 },
            "dataType": "json",
            "contentType": "application/json",
            "dataSrc": "results.data"
};
```

Comment: I don't know how this got marked as correct since it is not. The OP wanted to send JSON to the server, and this method will not send JSON. It sends the data URL encoded.  The answer provided by @Kavi is the correct answer. At least this is not the correct answer for version 1.10.24

Answer (score 1):

For datatable grids, It works when I tried [this](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/26699/post-datatable-data-to-server-in-json-format-with-column-names)

```
ajax: {
  url: ...,
  data: function ( d ) {
    return JSON.stringify({"name" : "foo"});
  },
"contentType": "application/json"

}
```

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. If you just try to pass the object the payload sent to the server is URL encoded so it's not JSON as the server is expecting. If you stringify it, it is garbled like in the OP's question. Creating the function fixes this since it bypasses whatever datatables is trying to do automatically. Thank you, @Kavi.